# Shiny navbarpage draws over elements from below

Tags: r, shiny, navbar

This is the problem I am trying to solve. My navbarpage overlaps other elements from below. Is there any way to put the navbarpage in the background? Or perhaps make the daterange input show it's calendar below its input box?

[image: Navbar page overlaps other elements]

The [documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/navbarPage.html) mentions using `fixed-top` or `fixed-bottom` for the `posotion` argument will cause the navbar to overlay your body content, unless you add padding.

Adding padding does not solve the problem though.

Here is a reproducible example -

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(class = 'headerrow', column(width = 12, style = "font-size: 30pt; line-height: 8vh; text-align:left; color:#FFFFFF; width = 100", tags$strong('Test')), tags$head(tags$style('.headerrow{height:8vh; background-color:#267dff}'))),
  navbarPage(
   'Navbar',
    tabPanel(
     'Menu1',
     sidebarPanel(
       selectInput('drink', 'Choose your poison', choices = c('Bloody Mary', 'Sex on the beach'), selected = 'Bloody Mary'),

       dateRangeInput('period', 'Date range', start = '2016-05-01', end = '2017-04-01', 
                   min = '2013-07-01', max = '2017-06-01', startview = 'year', format = 'mm/yyyy'),
    width = 2
  ),
  mainPanel(width = 10)
  ),
tabPanel('Menu2'),
tabPanel('Menu3'),
tabPanel('Menu4')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `z-index` to the div: `tags$style(HTML(".datepicker {z-index:99999 !important;}"))`

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(class = 'headerrow', column(width = 12, style = "font-size: 30pt; line-height: 8vh; text-align:left; color:#FFFFFF; width = 100", tags$strong('Test')), tags$head(tags$style('.headerrow{height:8vh; background-color:#267dff}'))),
  navbarPage(
    'Navbar',
    tabPanel(
      'Menu1',
      tags$style(HTML(".datepicker {z-index:99999 !important;}")),
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput('drink', 'Choose your poison', choices = c('Bloody Mary', 'Sex on the beach'), selected = 'Bloody Mary'),

        dateRangeInput('period', 'Date range', start = '2016-05-01', end = '2017-04-01', 
                       min = '2013-07-01', max = '2017-06-01', startview = 'year', format = 'mm/yyyy'),
        width = 2
      ),
      mainPanel(width = 10)
    ),
    tabPanel('Menu2'),
    tabPanel('Menu3'),
    tabPanel('Menu4')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```